# VS2010 project doesnt have x64 platform target

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have in my solution around 17 project, that has ANY CPU (x86 + x64) profiles in the Platform Target. Except one.

What can cause this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project is dependent on unmanaged x86 calls and doesn't provide code for x64.

Answer (score 0):

If the target assigned to that project is x64, it won't list it as an option for adding a new target.